# Setting user quota on a share in Win Server 08r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, user-management, disk-space-utilization

I have several shares on a server running 08r2 that I have users dumping files to.

I would like to limit each user to be able to use only a specific amount of the space (quota)

Any help on how to configure this is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the [File Server Resource Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755603(v=ws.10).aspx) and make per-user quotas.

You can use templates to enforce queries per-user or per-folder. In your case, you'll want user likely.